# turn string to array python

Tags: python, linux

How can I turn this string

```
"((145541L, u'/.stats/'), (175706L, u'///')"
```

to a json object in python such as

```
{'145541' : '/.stats/',
 '175706' : '///'
 }
```

I've been trying tuple() and others but it does

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get an invalid string representation of a nested tuple? I believe you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: by running  s.cursor.execute(sqlQuery)
 results = s.cursor.fetchall()

Comment: That's not a string, it's a tuple. You probably want to be using `MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor` (assuming mysql).

Comment: What do you mean by "a json object in Python"? There is no such thing. Your expected output is a `dict`. Do you want the JSON encoding of that `dict`, or the `dict` itself, or something different? (Your question is "turn string to array", which implies that you might want a `list` or `tuple` or `array.array` or `numpy.ndarray` or something else array-like, but I'm not sure what you would want there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do most probably have a tuple of tuples, and want to create a dictionary. To do so, try the following:

```
data = ((145541L, u'/.stats/'), (175706L, u'///'))
result = dict(data)
```

If what you have is really a string, add the initial line:

```
data = "((145541L, u'/.stats/'), (175706L, u'///'))"
data = eval(data)
result = dict(data)
```

As pointed by @Volatility, `eval` may be dangerous, since it evaluates **any** piece of code, not only literals. This way someone could execute commands on your program if you received commands on your strings.

To avoid so, you may use `ast.literal_eval` instead:

```
from ast import literal_eval
data = "((145541L, u'/.stats/'), (175706L, u'///'))"
result = dict(literal_eval(data))
```

Comment: `eval` is dangerous - you can use `ast.literal_eval` here

Comment: @Volatility Would you mind to add any explanation/example as on why is `eval` dangerous?

Comment: It's because it doesn't only evaluate literals, it can evaluate all sorts of code, and if that string comes from some random person using the program, they can easily 'hack' into your program.

Answer (score 7):

Quick fix:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "((145541L, u'/.stats/'), (175706L, u'///')"
>>> {str(k): v for (k, v) in ast.literal_eval(s + ')')}
{'175706': u'///', '145541': u'/.stats/'}
```

But you should really try looking into [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) instead.

Comment: It looks like he wants the keys as strings (and the values as `str` instead of `unicode`, but that probably doesn't matter, while `int` vs. `str` does).